# JAVA Replace image/picture in Presentation (PPTX) with Apache POI

Tags: java, image, powerpoint, apache-poi

Just want to know how to draw an Image I have in a buffered image into a PictureShape using POI.
I wrote the code below to do what I ask but with no success.

Thanks for reading and luckily helping out.

```
           for (int i = 0; i < listNewImage.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    Icon icon = listNewImage.get(i).getIcon();
                    BufferedImage im = (BufferedImage) iconToImage(icon);

                    Graphics2D g = im.createGraphics();

                    listImageShape.get(i).drawContent(g);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(EditorMenuWindows.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [pptx4j sample](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/pptx4j/java/org/pptx4j/samples/InsertPicture.java) I wrote which you may be able to adapt.  POI works along broadly similar lines (it uses XML Beans, not JAXB).